# How to create a dynamic dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I was trying to create a data frame and the reason why I gave the create a data frame in the below manner is to make it dynamic but the expression is passed as a string and the exec command is not able to create the data frame and assign to a variable.

Here is my code:

```
def fileReader(inputFileType,sourceFilePath,inputFileType):
 value ='true'
 header='header'


 a= "spark.read.option('"+header+"','"+value+"')."+inputFileType+"('"+sourceFilePath+"')"
 print(a)
 print(type(a))
 ds = exec(a)
 return 'True'
```

Comment: Please clarify the issue, and share a [mcve]. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try with a config file like below

```
import json
files = json.loads('{
  "fileA": {
    "header": "true",
    "inputFileType": "csv",
    "sourceFilePath": "path_to_fileA"
  },
  "fileB": {
    "header": "true",
    "inputFileType": "parquet",
    "sourceFilePath": "path_to_fileB"
  }
}')


df_dict = {}
for file in files:
    df_dict['file'] = spark.read.option('header',file["header"]).format(file["inputFileType"]).path(file["sourceFilePath"])
```

Then you get a dictionary of dataframes with different formats and file path.

Answer (score 1):

Hey got the answer...

```
def fileReader(inputFileType,sourceFilePath,inputFileType):
  value ='true'
  header='header'
  a= "spark.read.option('"+header+"','"+value+"')."+inputFileType+" 
  ('"+sourceFilePath+"')"
  print(a)
  print(type(a))
  ds = eval(a)
  return 'True'
```

the motive behind creating this function is to dynamically create data frames using different formats of files supported by pyspark.
Now using this function I can create a data frame any type of file formats that are supported by pyspark, by just passing the location and the format of files.

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using pyspark instead of using `exec` on strings representing spark commands. pyspark has a really nice interface for executing spark commands in python. It also has a handy function `csv` on the `pyspark.sql` module that [loads data from a csv file into a spark dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=read%20csv). Your code will look something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark =(SparkSession.builder
                    .appName(YOUR_APP_NAME)
                    .getOrCreate())
csv_df = spark.csv('path/to/csv')
```

However, if your data is stored in a csv, I suspect there isn't enough data to really warrant using spark, which has a lot of overhead and is meant for handling very large datasets. I'd recommend trying out pandas first, [which also has a handy way of loading csv data into a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and only switching to spark if your code is running too slowly with pandas.

Comment: Hi charlie, Its just not only for csv, its for other formats too, like parquet etc.

Comment: the reason why I am using exec is that I want to pass the file format dynamically, and not to be static for just only one format.